# Android app email attachment not going through in Gmail app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

My app creates a PDF file, saves it in `context.getFilesDir()`, and passes a `URI` using a content provider to launch an email `Intent`. My implementation works for every email app **except** Gmail.

What happens is the new email intent is launched and the PDF is attached, correct name and size, but after sending, the attachment is not received on the other end. Only the email subject and body. It does work (PDF goes through) in gmail *sometimes*. It seems to not work about 90% of the time.

**Edit:**

I've tried all possible storage locations, even omitting the content provider entirely and saving to a public folder. Same result.

It appears disabling gmail sync for the account used to send the email makes it work. So it must be related to the gmail app.

Relevant parts of code:

```
// Creating PDF
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

...

// Writing to file
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), mFileName);

try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    document.writeTo(outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printSackTrace();
}

Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.redacted.redacted.fileprovider", file);

// Email intent
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");

// To
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{mEmail});

// Subject
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getEmailSubject());

// Attachment
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

// Launch intent
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sending PDF..."));
```

**Manifest**

```
...
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.redacted.redacted.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
</provider>
...
```

**xml/paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="name" path="/" />
</paths>
```

I believe everything is implemented correctly as it works in Inbox, Samsung mail app, other email apps. Just Gmail it seems when it's sent to an address that's recieved an attachment before, the PDF doesn't come through.

Any idea why?

Comment: I have the same issue (except that instead of being inconsistent, sending never works from g-mail, but does work from other apps). I suspect that the problem is that Gmail is running asynchronously, and that the permission expires before it gets around to reading the attachment. I have not been able to resolve the issue. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set "mailto" Uri in intent to send emails to email clients like Gmail. and action will be ACTION_SENDTO instead of ACTION_SEND.

write code like this for your intent:

```
// Email intent
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));

// To    
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{mEmail});

// Subject
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getEmailSubject());

// Attachment
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

// Launch intent
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sending PDF..."));
```

Comment: I stated multiple times it works with every email client except Gmail. It does actually work with gmail except when sending to an address that's been sent an attachment before. Just tried your solution for the heck of it. Does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have attached PDF files in gmail android app. It is working as expected

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Document");

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("<p>Please find attached document "+url+" for you review.</p>");
       intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));

       intent.setType("text/html");
       intent.setType("application/pdf");

       intent.setType("message/rfc822");
       intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(pdfattachedfiles));

       startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"), ApplicationConstant.Content_pdf_constant);
```

[image]

Comment: where is the location of `pdfattachedfiles`, where is it saved? and have you tested with the gmail app?

Comment: Pdfattachedfiles is the file and it is located on phone storage directory. It is working fine with gmail. I have edited the answer check the screen shot

Comment: But which directory on storage? I'd like to place it in the `getExternalFilesDir()` or someplace appropriate for temporary files. I see you're not using a `ContentProvider` so it must be in a public folder?

Comment: Yes, it is in the downloads folder

Comment: Check this gist https://gist.github.com/Fazalcs13/b3a60298df02a549baafacce87a60db2#file-writepdffiles

Comment: Have you verified that Send *actually* sends the email *with* the attachment? I am having similar problems as the OP, but I can attach the file just fine, but when I actually hit Send gmail complains with a Notification that says "Couldn't send attachment", and the email gets sent but has no attachment. What is weird is that I can manually attach the file that failed to send and it sends just fine! Seems like something to do w/ passing the Uri via the Intent. This is on an older 5.1.1 (Lollipop) device. Code seems to work fine on newer clients. :/

Comment: HAH! PEBCAK! I was attaching a runtime compressed zip file, and in my onActivityResult I was deleting the zip file. Apparently my delete was happening quicker than Gmail could send it. Simple and obvious fix was to delay the delete a reasonable duration later (ex: 5 seconds).

Comment: I am receiving email with attachment. I have updated the gist please have a look.